# Ударение в фамилии Мухерджи

Tags: орфоэпия

Куда падает ударение в фамилии Мухерджи?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Это только сам/сама Мухерджи может сказать наверняка.
Ударение считается правильным то, на котором настаивает носитель.

По общим правилам (не абсолютным) ударения в тюркских фамилиях на чи/джи (Колпакчи, Бахчиванджи, Балыкчи) падает на последний слог. Но семейные традиции и некоторые другие факторы часто нарушают подобные закономерности.

(+++++)
Если вы о ней 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rani_Mukerji,
то англичане предлагают такой варитант: [/rɑːniː mᵿkhərdʒiː/]
То есть ударение в имени на первый, в фамилии на последний слог.

Ну пусть так и у нас будет, хотя странно.

Comment: "Англичане" - не аргумент. А про носителя - да, и это главное.

Answer (score 1):

В фамилии известной актрисы **Рани Мукерджи** ударение, скорее всего, падает на последний слог, если судить по английской транскрипции (звук iː  долгий):

Рани Мукерджи (бенг. রাণী মুখার্জী, [rɑ:niː mʉkhərdʒiː].